# How do i hide git-bash.exe and just run it in the background whilst I'm calling a git clone through a C# process?

Tags: c#, git, bash, github, process

Hello I have the following code

```
string newDist = destination + "/" + fileName;
var o = new Process
{
    StartInfo = 
    {
        FileName = pathToGitClient,
        Arguments = $"-c \"eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add {privateKey} && git clone {repoUrl} {repoDest}\""
    }
};
o.Start();
```

This basically creates a git clone process using git-bash.exe in my git folder. If i wanted to hide the command line window whilst it's cloning how would I do that?

I tried

```
o.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
o.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StartInfo.WindowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an instance of the [ProcessWindowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) enum.

```
o.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
// or
o.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

You will still need to set `UseShellExecute` to `false` for this to work.